# I cannot Create a NSURL that works when using stringByappendingString

Tags: html, ios

The following URL works correctly in Safari:

```
NSURL *conversionUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=100&From=ALL&To=USD];
```

The Following will not work but NSLog returns the same result.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

```
NSString *newStringURL =
   [[[[[  @"http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount="  stringByAppendingString:@"100"]stringByAppendingString:@"&from="]stringByAppendingString:@"ALL"]stri ngByAppendingString:@"&to="]stringByAppendingString:@"USD"];
NSURL *conversionUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:newStringURL];  
NSLog(@"URL= %@",conversionUrl);
URL= http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=100&from=ALL&to=USD
```

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference, but "from" and "to" are lowercase in your second string and uppercase in the first.

Comment: yeah apparently the case matters =/

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that all day without seeing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `NSString *newStringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=%@&From=%@&To=%@", @100, @"ALL", @"USD"];`

Simply replace the values such as @100 to whatever is needed.

Looks a lot cleaner than appending string with string.

And for others looking for the correct answer it is because the URL is case sensitive.

Helps stackoverflow users to see the answer in the answers section, not in the comments. Consider accepting this answer.